# CockroachDB upgrade not finalized

Tags: upgrade, docker, cockroachdb

I am running a three-node CockroachDB docker cluster (Debian OS) and I recently upgraded the cluster from version v21.1 to version v21.2 following the procedure outlined in the [documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.2/upgrade-cockroach-version) using the option

```sql
SET CLUSTER SETTING cluster.preserve_downgrade_option = '21.1';
```

Then I restarted the container of each node one at a time and when no issues arose I run

```sql
RESET CLUSTER SETTING cluster.preserve_downgrade_option;
```

Now all three nodes are running the same version and the **cluster.preserve_downgrade_option** is set to an empty string. Nonetheless, even after hours have elapsed since then, when I am trying to create a table which has a feature included in the 21.2 version

```sql
create table randdb.public.randtable
(
    name_surname varchar(30),
    update_tim TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() ON UPDATE now(),
    PRIMARY KEY (name_surname)
)
```

I get the error message

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: version 21.1-1152 must be finalized to use ON UPDATE
```

Other than this, the cluster seems to be fully functional. Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved. The issue was one long dead node which had not been decommissioned at the time of upgrade, causing the cluster to wait for that node to be upgraded before upgrading the cluster version.

This was dealt with by running

```
cockroach node decommission <dead_node_id> --certs-dir=<certs_dir> --host=<live_docker_hostname> --cluster-name=<cluster_name>
```